# python regex limit parenthesis to one time

Tags: python, regex

I have a problem in Python where program has to check whether or not user enters a phone number in valid format such as: `(111)-111-1111`
I got this program to work using Python regex `re.findall` function, however, later on I realized that program lets user to enter as many parentheses as he wants, for example: `(((((111)-111-1111` and this would still go trough the program as a valid format. 
Question. Is there a way to limit the number of parentheses  to the way the format would be as `(111)-111-1111`?
My code is as follows:

```
import re
number=input("Please enter phone number:  " )                    
x=re.findall('([(+*)]\d{3}[(+*)][a-]\d{3}[a-]\d{4})', number)
if (x):
    print("Perfect! Your format is valid: -->  " "'"+number+"'")
else:
    print("Not a valid format, please enter as (###)-###-####")
```

Comment: Don't remove the text of a solved question. Accept an answer with the check mark below. If you solved the problem and none of the answers are acceptable, write your own.

Answer (score 1):

You were really close to have your code working. 
You will just need to adapt your sample into:

```
import re

number=input("Please enter phone number:  " )
x=re.match('^([(+*)]\d{3}[(+*)][a-]\d{3}[a-]\d{4})$', number)
if (x):
  print("Perfect! Your format is valid: -->  " "'"+number+"'")
else:
  print("Not a valid format, please enter as (###)-###-####")
```

Where, instead of using `findall`, you use `match` as you are checking that the number does respect the pattern (the regex) and as you are not looking to extract some sub information from it.

Also you will need to add anchors (`^`, `$`) in your regex to enforce that the input string does not contain other characters in the beginning or at the end.

**Output:**

```
Please enter phone number:  '(111)-111-1111'
Perfect! Your format is valid: -->  '(111)-111-1111'
Please enter phone number:  '(((((111)-111-1111'
Not a valid format, please enter as (###)-###-#
```

Comment: Allan,
Thank you very much for your time and help. I did try to use re.match before, however, I did know that anchors might come that handy. Now it works just the way I wanted. 
Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

For validating mobile numbers like `(111)-111-1111` I don't think you need a overly complicated and incorrect regex like this `([(+*)]\d{3}[(+*)][a-]\d{3}[a-]\d{4})` Even if you put start anchor `^` and end anchor `$` it is going to validate following mobile numbers as valid which would be in correct,

```
)111(a111a1111
*111+-111-1111
```

[Check this demo to see how it allows invalid mobile numbers](https://regex101.com/r/EoouYh/1)

For validating mobile number like this `(111)-111-1111`, you can just use following regex,

```
^\(\d{3}\)-\d{3}-\d{4}$
```

**[Demo for correctly validating mobile numbers](https://regex101.com/r/vH2WlB/1)**

Let me know in case you want to allow any variations of this `(111)-111-1111` mobile number as valid.

Also, for validating a text, you should use `match` function instead of `findall` where later is used to extract information from a text and former for matching a text for validity.

Here is a sample python code which shows how you should validate your mobile numbers,

```
import re

arr = ['(111)-111-1111','(((((111)-111-1111',')111(a111a1111','*111+-111-1111']

for s in arr:
 if (re.match(r'^\(\d{3}\)-\d{3}-\d{4}$', s)):
  print(s, ' --> is Valid mobile number')
 else:
  print(s, ' --> is Not Valid mobile number')
```

Prints,

```
(111)-111-1111  --> is Valid mobile number
(((((111)-111-1111  --> is Not Valid mobile number
)111(a111a1111  --> is Not Valid mobile number
*111+-111-1111  --> is Not Valid mobile number
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the line below:

`x=re.findall('^\(\d{3}\)-\d{3}-\d{4}$', number)`

This also checks for beginning and ending characters.

Comment: Thank you very much! these anchors come very handy! I did not know about them!